# Android: app close unexpectly, but it's sooo strange

Tags: android, crash

my app is closing unexpecting, but it's strange because i'm at the beginning of the developing, so the app doesn't have nothing particular on it!
my first class:

```
package it.mi.action.codmmunicator_2ddecoder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Loading extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading);
    final int tempodiattesa=3000;
    Thread schermataattesa=new Thread(){
        int aspetta=0;
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                super.run();
                while(aspetta<tempodiattesa){
                    sleep(100);
                    aspetta+=100;
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("EXc="+e);
            }finally{
                startActivity(new      Intent(Loading.this,Lettore.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    schermataattesa.start();
}
}
```

and the second one:

```
package it.mi.action.codmmunicator_2ddecoder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Lettore extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.lettore);
}
}
```

when it goes on the second class, it crash.
the xml is a normal linear layout with an image on it.

i'm sure the android manifest is right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="it.mi.action.codmmunicator_2ddecoder" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <activity android:name="Loading" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Lettore" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and if i let the app start with Lettore it crash. i think the problem is on Lettore.java but it's absurd

can someone help me?
see that is not normal?

**this is my logcat:**

```
06-28 13:41:25.322: D/dalvikvm(403): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 51K, 53% free 2552K/5379K, external 716K/1038K, paused 61ms

06-28 13:41:29.353: D/AndroidRuntime(403): Shutting down VM

06-28 13:41:29.353: W/dalvikvm(403): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {it.mi.action.codmmunicator_2ddecoder/it.mi.action.codmmunicator_2ddecoder.Lettore} did not call through to super.onCreate()

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1613)

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

06-28 13:41:29.363: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

06-28 13:41:32.083: I/Process(403): Sending signal. PID: 403 SIG: 9
```

i'm sure the android manifest is right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="it.mi.action.codmmunicator_2ddecoder" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <activity android:name="Loading" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Lettore" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and if i let the app start with Lettore it crash. i think the problem is on Lettore.java but it's absurd

Comment: have you put the entry for Lettore in manifest..

Comment: you gotta post your logcat man

Comment: Lettore activity is not calling the super.onCreate(). Execption is really clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
super.onCreate() is missing in Lettore class
```

..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(); //<-----------------------------add this
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.lettore);
}
```

1 - confirm have you put the entry for Lettore in manifest.

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(Loading.this,Lettore.class)); will work with no issues.may be he has not registered it in manifest.

Comment: Dheeresh-You are an animal. I always see you answering these android questions so quickly.

Comment: That was in no way an insult haha, nor was it crude language. But ok

Comment: sorry, it looks like as insult, I agree some people complained about my English and I think you are also doing same but on high pitch.... I am really really sorry if I am taken it as wrong

Comment: Yeah sorry, I guess it is sort of slang, calling someone an animal. It was not meant to be an insult in anyway.

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be insulting at all.

Comment: Thanks Zak, but I think imran answered it first, so Please accept his answer ......

Answer (score 2):

change your code as :
replace `finally` block :

```
finally{
                startActivity(new      Intent(Loading.this,Lettore.class));
                finish();
            }
```

with

```
   finally{
        Loading.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {     
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  Loading.this.startActivity(new Intent(Loading.this,Lettore.class));
                  finish();
}
                });

        }
```

and make sure you have register your Lettore Activity in manifast.xml as:

```
<Activity android:name=".Lettore" />
```

EDIT : 
add super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  in Lettore Activity  as:

```
package it.mi.action.codmmunicator_2ddecoder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Lettore extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.lettore);
}
}
```

Comment: @Zak : no problem.can u edit your post with logcat stacktrace when app is crashing

Comment: add super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); in Lettore

Comment: add as public class Lettore extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);//your code..

Comment: incredible! i've miss it! ahahahah! i need a vacation XD

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
```

to your code

Comment: this is the answer im sure unfortunately, too simple for us all to catch :D